# In GDB, how can I set 'exec-wrapper env' to multiple environmental variables?

Tags: gdb, environment-variables, environment

In GDB you can set the environmental variables for a process using `set exec-wrapper env 'MYENVVAR=...'`. This works great, but I'm not sure how to set multiple ones - is there some sort of delimiter you have to use? I'd like to set both `LD_PRELOAD` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` for a process. How would I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
set exec-wrapper env VAR1=val1 VAR2=val2
```

to set multiple environment variables. The values should be appropriately quoted for your shell, so putting single quotes around them would be a good idea.

In slightly more detail:

The `set exec-wrapper` command sets a string variable to contain the rest of the command line.

When it comes time to run your executable, `gdb` does something like the following pseudo-code:

```
shell_cmd = "exec ";
if (exec_wrapper)
     shell_cmd += exec_wrapper + " ";
shell_cmd += quote_shell_metacharacters(exec_file);
execl(getenv("SHELL"), "sh", "-c", shell_cmd, (char *)0);
```

So, `exec-wrapper` can be any command line that makes sense when preceded by `"exec "` in your shell.

Comment: Thanks, very thorough answer!