# reduce stack size in debug session to catch endless recursion

Tags: c++, linux, recursion, gdb, stack-overflow

I have a algorithm which "sometimes" did not break the recursion and ends up in a stack overflow. Now I want to debug that situation. gdb points me directly to the line where I overwrite the stack boarder, but it is impossible to get a stacktrace because gdb needs endless time to unwind the stack and display it in ddd.

I now simply want to reduce the stack size to get the corruption much earlier. So I need a way to reduce to stack for my running task. There are no threads involved so it should be not such a big deal.

But I have no idea if gdb itself has an option to manipulte the stack (size) itself or I need to programmatic change the size at start of my prog or I can maybe reduce the size from the os command line ( linux ) after starting the debug session.

Maybe it is also possible the stop if the call tree reaches a maximum depth if gdb has such an option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use `ulimit -s` (stack_size) in shell where you run your program or you can do it programmatically [Change stack size for a C++ application in Linux during compilation with GNU compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275550/change-stack-size-for-a-c-application-in-linux-during-compilation-with-gnu-com)

EDIT:

We can write simple nohup-like program, which send `SIGSTOP` to itself, and than execute it's arguments. Let's name it runpaused

```
//runpaused.c
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    raise(SIGSTOP);
    return execvp(argv[1], argv+1);
}
```

Than, we can do next things:
compile runpaused

```
$ gcc runpaused.c -o runpaused
```

limit stack for current shell

```
$ ulimit -s 32
```

run our program via runpaused, use sh as example

```
$ ./runpaused sh -c "echo Hello"
```

From other terminal:
find it's `PID`

```
$ ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep runpaused
```

load gdb with our program

```
$ gdb $(which sh)
```

attach to `PID`

```
(gdb) attach PID
```

send signal `SIGCONT` from `gdb`

```
(gdb) signal SIGCONT
```

continue program execution from `gdb`

```
(gdb) continue
```

After several times of continuing, we get what we want.

Comment: using ulimit -s can not help, because this effects the debug session and not only the program which should be debugged. Is there a chance to set ulimit -s from gdb? But your link to the programmatically reduction of stacksize fits my problem. Maybe you can change your answer for other users.

Comment: To set the ulimit only in the target, try `(gdb) set exec-wrapper sh -c 'ulimit -s 32;exec "$0" "$@"'` . More about the semantics of `exec-wrapper` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27510210/2554472).