# GDB changing dynamic linking behavior

Tags: c, gdb, code-injection, ld-preload

I'm working on a project that involves the use of **LD_PRELOAD** to overwrite symbols that are dynamically linked from a shared object at runtime, for example:

`LD_PRELOAD=/some_library.so ./myapp`

I'm getting a segfault when running the executable, but only when I run it *outside* of GDB. Another detail is that I'm looking up the address of the symbol in the executable using bfd -- and this address matches the address I've found using `objdump -d ./myapp`, but when I call that address at runtime *without* GDB it segfaults. I'm happy to add code / more details on the exact use case, but my question is really: How does GDB change dynamic linking behavior? My suspicion is that the symbol I'm trying to override is being relocated to another region of memory at runtime, but I don't know how that process works, or how to lookup the relocated address (outside of using gdb at runtime)

I've tried looking up the symbol manually:

`root@server:/workspace/test_apps# objdump -dC ./myapp  | grep -i myfunction 0000000000001b65 <__sti____myFunction()>:`

and in my LD_PRELOADED library I'm trying to call it like this:

```
    void (*myFunc)(void) =
        (void(*)(void)) 0x1b65;

    myFunc();
```

If I look up that same symbol using gdb without the preloaded library, I see something interesting:

```
root@server:/workspace/test_apps# gdb --args env 
 LD_PRELOAD=/some_library.so ./myapp
(gdb) info functions
...
0x0000000000001b65  __sti____myFunction()
```

but then if I run it with GDB, and then lookup the symbol, it's been relocated to a different address:

```
root@server:/workspace/test_apps# gdb --args env LD_PRELOAD=/some_library.so ./myapp
(gdb) run
(gdb) info functions
...
0x0000555555555b65  __sti____myFunction()
```

The last thing I'll note is that if I use this new address (0x0000555555555b65) to call the function, instead of the address I looked up earlier (0x1b65), it works (no segfault), but *only* in the context of gdb. Outside of GDB it doesn't work with either address.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show how you configure `gdb`.  Presumably you're using something like `set environment LD_PRELOAD /some_library.so`?

Comment: @G.M. sorry about that -- edited.

Comment: @JohnBollinger that makes sense -- but in my case I know that it works consistently in the context of GDB. In other words if I hardcode that address (0x0000555555555b65) and run it repeatedly within GDB, the address remains the same from run to run. I'm wondering if GDB somehow changes the behavior of this process.

Comment: ASLR aside, symbols in shared libraries do not have their addresses assigned at library-building time, so that you could look them up in the shared object in the first place.  Handling that is what relocation is all about.  Thus, you cannot rely on hard-coding symbol addresses.  You must either let the dynamic linker do its job to resolve symbols for you automatically, or engage `dlsym()` and friends to request the DL's services manually.

Comment: Note that syntax such as `gdb --args env LD_PRELOAD=/some_library.so ./myapp` won't work: you're asking `gdb` to debug `env`.

Comment: Thanks for all your responses. To make it clear, I understand that the address is being relocated at runtime and that using that address is invalid. My question is more around how GDB affects the behavior of dynamic linking, if at all.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm getting a segfault when running the executable, but only when I run it outside of GDB.

It's not *entirely* unusual for an application to only crash outside GDB -- debugging *does* change timing and (by default) disables ASLR.

You should be able to collect a `core` dump from "outside" GDB, then debug that `core` with GDB: `gdb ./myapp core`.

> `gdb --args env ...`

That's not doing what you want -- you are asking GDB to debug the `env` binary.

The right way to invoke GDB in your case is:

```
gdb -q ./myapp

(gdb) set env LD_PRELOAD /some_library.so
(gdb) run
```

Or, in a single command: `gdb -ex 'set env LD_PRELOAD /some_library.so' -ex run ./myapp`

Note: depending on which functions `some_library.so` defines, this still may not work (may interfere with the shell which GDB invokes for output redirection). You may also have to use `set startup-with-shell off` ([documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/Starting.html)).

See also this related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27510210/50617).

> `void (*myFunc)(void) = (void(*)(void)) 0x1b65;`

You have a [PIE executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code), which is relocated at runtime to 0x555... address. *Of course* `0x1b65` will not work -- that's not the address the application actually runs at.

To make debugging simpler, rebuild the `myapp` binary with `-no-pie` (if you can).

Comment: For anyone looking at this question later, using the args parameter is actually valid syntax to use GDB with LD_PRELOAD, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45212399/9139580

Comment: @stumbling.fool it's valid, but it likely isn't going to give the best debug experience, you will initially be debugging `env` itself, so commands like `start` are not going to do what you expect.